# Python compare two SHA512 hashes

Tags: python, hash, sha512

I have two SHA512 hashes with salt:

```
h1 = "412e00cc45afb8d2d5675bf5de0d1bb83eb85ab4af2c5560c8cc580feeb319565cde4e8d57ff847c0c6d9c6681d68d7850da594932d66fd65db133b19e5b31ec:9c0d2ff09e8c43babc49d42ad215e0fa"

h2 = "bc80293178d0aa302f5372a744a2acd3d4f7350b635bcdbded1f95fba187a4d04b429b30fb94daed2a94be3ec2c9ed5a110827f3a794b9f8c40fcdd41015e2c2:1a8de82d82134aecbab7f6d0c37c8444"
```

Is it possible to compare them, to derive if they are generated from the same password without having the password?

```
hashlib.sha512(h1.encode).digest() == hashlib.sha512(h2.encode).digest()
```

Comment: Of course it is.  If they were generated from the same password, the two strings would be identical.  They aren't, so they weren't.

Comment: A hash is unique for a specific input, they cannot be the same. But if the salt is different for the same password hash should be different.

Comment: Not if you don't know or can't guess the salt.

Comment: The point of hashing passwords is that you cannot get any information about the password if you only have the hash.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Even with identical passwords, the strings would not be identical, because the salts are different.

Comment: So now i am a little bit confused, cause the hashes are generated from the same password. Can i compare them in any way for equality?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance: Looking at the strings, they seem to be of the form `"hash:salt"`, so it looks like they have the salt.

Comment: This means if i use the same salt (but different hashes for same password) i could compare for equality?

Comment: Why are you asking this? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You've got both hash and salt - your strings are of the form `hash:salt` - but even with that, you would still need to crack the password of at least 1 hash to determine if the hashes came from the same password with different salts. Preventing attackers from easily determining if two hashes came from the same password is one of the primary reasons salts exist.

(As an aside, SHA-512 is a terrible choice of password hash, as it is not designed for the job and is far too quick to evaluate. Just cracking the password may be pretty easy.)

Comment: Thanks! So what if i have two hashes with the same salt?

Comment: @cheat.008: Then simple string comparison suffices.

Comment: @cheat.008: But if all hashes have the same salt then you lose all the benefits of having a salt in the first place.